# Azure Web API authorize token generated by Azure AD and Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have react native app which uses Azure AD B2C (as it is available outside our organization) and a backend admin SPA with Azure AD as it is only for our employees.

I have a node backend with provides api for both the app, now how to validate the tokens generated by AD B2C app and AD app.

One solution is to use Azure AD as external identity provider in Azure AD B2C and use Azure AD B2C app for the both RN external facing app and backend admin SPA, this will work,  the issue being here is we will have employee information on both AD & AD B2C.

What is the right way of doing these kind of integration.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Handle it in the back-end side / API side. So essentially, in the API side, you have two or more ways of authenticating a user.

In the case of AD and AD B2C, it'll be like setting up two JWT auth providers.